# How to send a react-created cookie to flask to be used in flask session?

Tags: reactjs, flask, cookies, flask-session

My code currently consists of a frontend in react and a flask backend api. I'm trying to establish a session in my backend using flask sessions, but I'm unable to, since flask never makes contact with the user, and all requests go through the frontend. To that end, I'm trying to post cookies to

In the frontend, I have something like

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
class thingy extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
          this.backendurl = 'localhost:5000'
          const cookies = new Cookies();
          this.username = this.props.match.params.user


          cookies.set('UserName', ''+JSON.stringify(this.username), { path: 
               '/profile' });


     }
     onclick = ()=>{
      #post something using axios that sends the cookie to the flask backend so it can be processed
}

}
     render(){
          return(
               <button onClick = {this.onclick}>Click Here</button>
          )
     }
}
```

backend:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
Session(app)
@app.route('/user',methods=['POST'])
def info():
    #do something with the cookie that react posted in order to user flask_session
return user.name
```

Does someone know how to send the cookies from react to flask, and then input the cookies recieved by flask into the flask session?

Comment: Cookies are automatically sent by your browser with every HTTP request that they apply to. There's no need to explicitly send them. All you need is to grab the cookies in flask.

Comment: @Rodentman87 Is that possible even though the user's browser never makes contact with flask? I thought the server was the only thing that touched the backend, so it wouldn't work to take the user's cookies.